# Use core.async's >! and <! outside go blocks

Tags: clojure

I'm trying to implement a (very) simple actor model prototype in clojure. Each actor would have, as the loop to handle the arrival of messages, a `go-loop`. I wanted to invoke, inside this `go-loop`, functions that would either take from or put into a channel. I really wanted parking behaviour on these inner channel operations, but I can't actually use `<!` or `>!` to do it so, because the operations wouldn't be directly inside the `go-loop`. Can I use macros to circumvent such limitation? If so, how would I do it?

To illustrate the issue simply, in the following snippet, how can I change `foo` so that the code actually compiles and I get parking behaviour?

```
(defn main-loop
  [ch]
  (async/go-loop [] (foo ch) (recur)))
(defn foo [ch] (>! ch "Hello, World!"))
```

Comment: You can't. They must be used in a go. `>!` isn't a function that actually does anything. They get translated by the go into useful code. They're just place markers. Look up their definitions using ctrl+B in IntelliJ.

Comment: I not experienced enough with `async` to know exactly when `go`s are appropriate, but why can't you just use a `go` here?

Comment: It would be a different program. Not that this one would ideally do anything useful - it would just print "Hello, World!" forever-, but I was just interested in providing a tiny illustration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use macros to write any code that you could write by hand, and that's all. So if you just want your functions to be convenient shorthand for using `>!` inline, then sure, you can replace the functions with macros. If you want to do something fancier, like map that function over a list of messages, then you can't, because that would involve bundling them up in a function to pass to `map`.

A simple example would just be

```
(defmacro foo [ch]
  `(>! ~ch "Hello, World!"))
```

Whether this is the solution to your problem, or something else is (such as using `>!!`), depends on what you want to be able to do with these things.

Answer (score 2):

As Carcigenicate said, the `>!` form must be inside a `go` loop as it is just a giant macro that does code generation/reformating.  Note also, the `>!` cannot be inside a function called within the `go` loop, since the `go` macro can't see inside the called function to do the necessary reformatting.

The `>!!` form does briefly use a java thread & locks to do the necessary synchronization, but this is a microscopic cost that you shouldn't worry about.

For convenience, I like to think of the async functions as follows:

```
  >!    =>  "put-go"     (must be in a go loop - parking semantics)
  >!!   =>  "put-now"    (can be anywhere - blocking/immediate effect)
  put!  =>  "put-later"  (can be anywhere - non-blocking/delayed effect)
```

You can see some examples of these functions in action [in these unit tests](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo/blob/master/test/tst/tupelo/async.cljc).

Comment: Wouldn't using `<!!` cause blocking of the go blocks' threadpool as a whole, instead of just blocking the thread inside the go block that uses it?

Comment: [The original blog post on clojure.core.async](http://clojure.com/blog/2013/06/28/clojure-core-async-channels.html) provides a good overview of the rational and more details on parking/blocking threads.